# Do I need virtualenv if I have tox?

Tags: python, virtualenv, tox

According to the [`tox` documentation](https://tox.wiki/en/3.26.0/#what-is-tox), it is a "*[`virtualenv`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv) management tool*". So, when I create a new project, do I still need `virtualenv` if `tox` can do a better job for multiple Python versions virtual environment setup?

Comment: You should still have it for running and debugging.

Comment: Did you try any of the examples from the documentation? Did you try reading further into the documentation, in order to understand what `tox` specifically does and how it works? The question seems strange as asked - of course a tool for managing virtualenvs, will require that you use virtualenvs. It just might be creating them for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow-up to @sinoroc's answer:

You can also use `tox` to create a development environment with the following command:

```
tox devenv my-dev-env
```

where `my-dev-env` is an arbitrary path name of your choice in which tox will to create the virtual environment. So in this case tox will create a virtual environment in the `my-dev-env` directory.

For more information see tox CLI documentation: https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.1/cli_interface.html#tox-devenv-(d)

Answer (score 5):

`tox` and `virtualenv` are meant for different use cases and have different workflows.

The fact that `tox` creates virtual environments is kind of an implementation detail. Its goal is to run the current project's test suite against multiple versions of the Python interpreters and/or multiple combinations of the project's dependencies. Its goal is not to create virtual environments. On the other hand `virtualenv`'s (or even Python's own [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)) only goal is to create virtual environments.

While one can use `tox` as primary tool to create Python virtual environments, in my experience it is much more convenient to use `virtualenv` (or `venv`) for this.

---

Now, if the goal is to be able to clearly define a list of virtual environments that are somewhat reproducible by each of the project's contributors on their own development machine, `tox` might have some advantages, since it is possible to define these environments in the `tox.ini` configuration file that can be shared with all contributors. In such a case one might also consider tools such as the following that are also helpful to create development environments and are actually meant for this use case:

- [*`hatch`*](https://pypi.org/project/hatch/)
- [*`pdm`*](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/)
- [*`pipenv`*](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/)
- [*`poetry`*](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/)
- and more

Comment: ```
With tox, it is necessary to edit the tox.ini configuration file in order to then be able to create a new virtual environment.
```

This is not true in the strict sense.

You can always create a new virtual env by just typing `tox -e` and adding a python identifier, e.g. `tox -e py310`, even if that env has not been defined before. Also you can always create arbitrary envs with the `--devenv` cli option, see my answer below.